# Why is there NullPointerException on Context that is already declared?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm getting an `android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference` on a context variable that has already been defined.  I'm following the Big Nerd Ranch Guide for Android development but the code is giving me this seemingly unwarranted error.

This is where I am declaring my Context variable `mContext`:

```
public class CrimeLab {
    private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;

    private List<Crime> mCrimes = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
...
}
```

But this line of code is throwing a Null Object Reference:

```
public CrimeLab(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext(); <- This one
        mDatabase = new CrimeBaseHelper(mContext)
                .getWritableDatabase();
        mCrimes = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Here is the stacktrace.  I tried different ways of declaring the Context but it all gave the same error.

```
Process: myapp.onur.criminalintent, PID: 5095
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp.onur.criminalintent/myapp.onur.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
     at myapp.onur.criminalintent.CrimeLab.<init>(CrimeLab.java:26)
```

**EDIT** This is my entire CrimeLab.java class

```
public class CrimeLab {
    private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;

    private List<Crime> mCrimes = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public void addCrime(Crime c){
        mCrimes.add(c);
    }

    public CrimeLab(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        mDatabase = new CrimeBaseHelper(mContext)
                .getWritableDatabase();
        mCrimes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static CrimeLab get(Context context) {
        if (sCrimeLab == null) {
            sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab(context);
        }return sCrimeLab;
    }

    public List<Crime> getCrimes() {
        return mCrimes;
    }

    public Crime getCrime(UUID id){
        for (Crime crime : mCrimes){
            if(crime.getID().equals(id)){
                return crime;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide the piece of code that's creating this kind of object, CrimeLab, by calling its constructor.

Comment: I can't really spot it.

Comment: Somewhere you are creating `new CrimeLab(...)` **or** `CrimeLab.get(...)`

Comment: if you added your full stacktrace, we could tell you where that is at

Comment: By the way, you *already have* a Context, so why do you need to use `getApplicationContext()` at all?

Comment: @cricket_007 ask the authors of Big Nerd Ranch Guide.

Comment: @cricket_007 Unless its UI related it's frequently best to use the application context.  For example, if you're making a singleton class that will be used by multiple activities, it can't use the activity context.  If your class saves a context, it should never save the main one it should save the application context to minimize harm if the object is leaked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere, you are calling `new CrimeLab(null)` or are otherwise passing `null` into the `CrimeLab` constructor.

In your now-updated question, you are creating a new `CrimeLab` in:

```
public static CrimeLab get(Context context) {
    if (sCrimeLab == null) {
        sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab(context);
    }return sCrimeLab;
}
```

Hence, the `Context` being passed into `get()` is `null`. So, find where you are calling `CrimeLab.get()` and fix the parameter so that it is not `null`.

Comment: I just went through all my java files and couldn't spot anything like that.

Comment: @OnurOzbek it is not that is explicit like that, you are passing a context that is null

Comment: Would it help if I placed all my Java files here (too long tho)

Comment: I've placed my CrimeLab.java file.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks a lot.  You were very helpful.  Also, is my question bad?  Idk why it was downvoted twice.  If you think it was a well asked question, do you mind giving me an upvote?

P.S:  I love your books.

Comment: @OnurOzbek: Without the source of `CrimeLab`, it would have been difficult to help you, and people may have downvoted you prior to that edit. Also, usually a `NullPointerException` is not that hard to track down, so perhaps some people downvoted you for "does not show any research effort".

Comment: It was a `NullObjectReference`.  Isn't there a difference?

Comment: @OnurOzbek: Your stack trace shows a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  The issue was in another class.  It didn't explicity say `null` but it was passing a faulty variable.  All I had to do was to remove it.

Comment: Please show the code that you changed to help others with this problem

Comment: I had a line `Context context = new Context(this)` in another class that was not used.  Removing that solved the problem.

Comment: That was in an Activity, and outside of `onCreate`, i'm guessing?

Comment: In my experience, you never need to make a `new Context()` since an Activity is a Context, and you almost always have an Activity reference

Comment: Yes.  It was outside of `onCreate`.  Also, I have no idea why I was downvoted twice.  What was wrong with my question?

Comment: You cut off the stacktrace the says where the exception started in your code and you were missing a [mcve]